# SOAP API in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, soap, ionic-framework

I am having trouble sending post data to a soap api in `angularjs`, i constructed the post data as an xml string and set the appropriate headers yet i still get the http error callback whenever the post request is instantiated, below is my code

```
var mydata = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soap12:Body><Query xmlns="http://myurl.com/"><Policy_Debit_NoteNo>123Asewe</Policy_Debit_NoteNo></Query></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>"

var header = {
                "content-type":"application/soap+xml",
                "Accept": "application/soap+xml"
             };

$http.post("http://myurl.com/mservice/service.asmx",mydata,header)
     .then(function(res){
             //success
             alert( "success: " + JSON.stringify(res) );
           }, 
           function(err) {
             //error
             alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err) );
      });
```

Comment: And what is error message?

Comment: "The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported"

Comment: It would be better to add error message into the question to have complete one. It looks like your server expect different Content-Type in header.

Answer (score 0):

First suspect is headers. According to [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) it should be

```
var header = {
            "Content-Type":"application/soap+xml",
            "Accept": "application/soap+xml"
         };
var config = {
    headers: header
};

$http.post("http://myurl.com/mservice/service.asmx", mydata, config)
   .then(function(res){
         //success
         alert( "success: " + JSON.stringify(res) );
       }, 
       function(err) {
         //error
         alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(err) );
  });
```

Since your url contains `.asmx`, is ASP.NET server, check default Content-Type for that server, may be it does not support `application/soap+xml`, so try `application/xml` or even `text/xml`.

If it does not help try to use the following:

```
$http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: 'http://myurl.com/mservice/service.asmx',
   datatype: 'xml',
   data: mydata 
   contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8"
 }).success(function(data,status, headers, config){
   if(status == '200'){
     alert(data.d);
   }
 }).error(function(data,status, headers, config){alert("error: " + status});
```

Comment: @TobiSkillZ So you have tried with `application/xml` and `text/xml`? it's hard to diagnose this without knowing what happens of server side... BTW, usually you need another header for SOAP request, something like `SOAPAction: http://myurl.com/mservice/service.asmx/PostMyData`

Comment: i have tried with both application/xml and text/xml ... i also added the SOAPAction to the header but that yielded nothing

Comment: OK, more data is needed to diagnose problem, regarding server... do you have access it server code/doc? asmx services can work with JSON as well. I don't see what also it could be...